# Bitcoin Core wallet fails to load and requires reindex after I already did it

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, wallet, synchronization

My Bitcoin Core is synchronized. But I can't open a wallet, it says that I might need a reindex. Though I already did it. Also I can't do dumpprivkey because it says that no wallet is loaded. 
How can I make it work or at least get my private key in order to use another wallet..?

Comment: Are you pruning?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, I am

Comment: Do you use the newest version of bitcoin core?

Comment: @GašperČefarin Yes, v0.19.1